# Delphi ZeosLib: Hot to enable Sqlite3 foreign_keys?

Tags: delphi, sqlite, foreign-keys, zeos

I'm using ZEOSDBO-7.1.4 with Delphi 7 to manage my application sqlite3 database.
I've created some foreign keys to allow DELETE CASCADE remove rows from the details table. But by default foreign keys disabled, so you have to enable it at the begining of work with DB. 
I had tried ExceuteDirect('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON') right after Connect but it didn't help. Then I had tried to call PRAGMA after transaction open and before the query, but it also didn't help.

**How can I enable Sqlite3 foreign_keys with ZEOSDbo in Delphi?**

Answer (score 0):

The answer in ZEOSDBO sources!

Just provide a property `foreign_keys=True` to the connection object before opening a connection.

The code:

```
...    
FDbConnection.Protocol := 'sqlite-3';
FDbConnection.Properties.Add('foreign_keys=TRUE');
FDbConnection.Connect;
```